# Xcode Field +[number] unless max value

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have some field values that I wish to set a min and a max on. The first field (_EvTotal) needs a different min and max to the second field (_HpTotal).

At the moment a button (eg the HpPlusOne shown below) can be pressed an infinite amount of times with no cap on the number. If I wished to set an example limit of 210 for the first field (in this case _EvTotal) and an example limit of 112 for the second field, how would I best go about this?

Edit: Once the number hits the cap, eg it is at 200 and someone presses the 50 button, how can I make it hit the cap but go no higher? The explanations provided so far simply set the field back to zero (this is my fault for not explaining properly & the resetting back to zero could also be me making a mistake).

```
- (IBAction)HpPlusOne:(id)sender {
    int counterNow, CounterLater;
    counterNow=[_EvTotal intValue];
    CounterLater=counterNow+1;
    [_EvTotal setIntValue:CounterLater];
    int hpNow, hpLater;
    hpNow=[_HpTotal intValue];
    hpLater=hpNow+1;
    [_HpTotal setIntValue:hpLater];

}

- (IBAction)HpPlusTwo:(id)sender {
    int counterNow, CounterLater;
    counterNow=[_EvTotal intValue];
    CounterLater=counterNow+2;
    [_EvTotal setIntValue:CounterLater];
    int hpNow, hpLater;
    hpNow=[_HpTotal intValue];
    hpLater=hpNow+2;
    [_HpTotal setIntValue:hpLater];
}

- (IBAction)HpPlusTen:(id)sender {
    int counterNow, CounterLater;
    counterNow=[_EvTotal intValue];
    CounterLater=counterNow+10;
    [_EvTotal setIntValue:CounterLater];
    int hpNow, hpLater;
    hpNow=[_HpTotal intValue];
    hpLater=hpNow+10;
    [_HpTotal setIntValue:hpLater];
}

- (IBAction)HpPlusFifty:(id)sender {
    int counterNow, CounterLater;
    counterNow=[_EvTotal intValue];
    CounterLater=counterNow+50;
    [_EvTotal setIntValue:CounterLater];
    int hpNow, hpLater;
    hpNow=[_HpTotal intValue];
    hpLater=hpNow+50;
    [_HpTotal setIntValue:hpLater];
}
```

Last of all apologies if this has already been answered, I found other answers on similar questions but they were about text fields directly editable by the end user. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

To your question: How hard is it to do an `if` before assigning the value to `_HpTotal`?

```
- (NSInteger)limitHp:(NSInteger)hp toMax:(NSInteger)max andMin:(NSInteger)min {
    if (hp < max) {
        return max;
    }
    if (hp > min) {
        return min;
    }
    return hp;
}

  - (IBAction)HpPlusFifty:(id)sender {
    int counterNow, CounterLater;
    counterNow=[_EvTotal intValue];
    CounterLater=counterNow+50;
    [_EvTotal setIntValue:CounterLater];
    int hpNow, hpLater;
    hpNow=[_HpTotal intValue];
    hpLater=hpNow+50;
    NSInteger limitedHp = [self limitHp:hpLater toMax:MAX_HP andMin:MIN_TP];
    [_HpTotal setIntValue:limitedHp];
}
```

---

On a side not, your code is **VERY** bad. You have 4 functions (each like 10 lines long) which have only one int different.

```
- (IBAction)HpPlusOne:(id)sender {
    [self increaseHpWith:1];

}

 - (IBAction)HpPlusTwo:(id)sender {
    [self increaseHpWith:2];
}

 - (IBAction)HpPlusTen:(id)sender {
    [self increaseHpWith:10];
}

 - (IBAction)HpPlusFifty:(id)sender {
    [self increaseHpWith:50];
}

 - (void)increaseHpWith:(NSInteger)difference {
    int counterNow, CounterLater;
    counterNow=[_EvTotal intValue];
    CounterLater=counterNow+50;
    [_EvTotal setIntValue:CounterLater];
    int hpNow, hpLater;
    hpNow=[_HpTotal intValue];
    hpLater=hpNow+50;
    NSInteger limitedHp = [self limitHp:hpLater toMax:MAX_HP andMin:MIN_TP];
    [_HpTotal setIntValue:limitedHp];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the overly simple question, and thanks for your help. I'm afraid this is maybe the third app I have tried to make, so I am aware my code is very bad. On the upside it is three more apps than I had worked on before I started learning. I will see how I go making this work.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a cleaner solution, you could just have a `@property` for hp, then override its setter and getter with the logic needed to limit it eg:

```
//define in your header
@property (nonatomic) int hp; 
@property int maxHp = 210;
@property int minHp = 0;

//in your .m file
- (void) setHp: (int) hp {
    _hp = hp;
    if(_hp > self.maxHp){
        _hp = self.maxHp //if its more than 210, set it to 210
    }
    if(_hp <= self.minHp){
        _hp = self.minHp;
        [self playerDeath]; //bonus of calling other useful methods from just setting the value of this variable
    }
}
```

later in your code you can just use it like

```
self.hp = 200;
self.hp += 20; //will be set to 210 actually
self.hp -= 500; //will be set to 0 and trigger [self playerDeath];
```

repeat these methods for each different type of field

Comment: That does look a lot neater than what I have. Sadly as I am a **very** new learner I am not that advanced, but I will see how I go. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: no worries, everyone is new at some point, what i said in my answer isnt too advanced, just google around for how @properties work, they not too difficult to understand, and can be very useful for stuff you are trying to do. they basically just normal variables that allow you to add in some functionality to them like i have demonstrated.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding. If I wanted it not to return to zero when it hit the max, but rather to go no higher - what would be my best course of action?

Comment: well either bite the bullet and try refactor your code to use properties like ive shown (it will limit the value like how you want) otherwise @Lord Zsolt's answer will do the trick as well if you dont want to edit your code too much

Comment: although looking at Zsolts answer, it looks like his > and < are the wrong way round in his if statement for the `limitHP:` function

Comment: You are correct there, I switched them to the proper order and it seems to work now.